# How to solve an equation with two variables in python

Tags: python, variables, numpy, equation-solving

So, I want to solve an equation z with two variables (x and y having 50 values each, for example). I want to calculate something like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 51)
y = np.linspace(100, 150, 51)

z=y-x

print z

with open("output_data.csv","w") as out_file:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        #print i
        out_string=""
        out_string+=str(x[i])
        #out_string+=str(real(ky2)[i])
        #print out_string
        out_string += "," + str(z[i])
        out_string += "\n"
        out_file.write(out_string)
```

However I want to calculate the first x with all the y's the the second x with all; y's again and so on, until I get a set of 50 values of z, each set with 50 values. Then save in a 50 column file.

What my code is doing so fat is calculating only 50 z's for the 1st x and 1st y, 2nd x and 2nd y and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code so you compute `z` inside the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    words = []
    z = y-x[i]
    words.append(str(x[i]))
    words.append(", ".join((str(_z) for _z in z)))
    outfile.write(": ".join(words))
    outfile.write("\n")
```

With your code, you only compute `z` one time (outside the loop) and this does an item-wise difference of `y` and `x` as you see.

Having said this, you should change your code to not do `str += ...`. If you are accumulating strings, use a list instead:

```
words = []
words.append(str(x[i]) ...
```

Comment: I did the first part and it really works fine, but the replacing str by words didn't really work. Could you be a little more clear in this part?

Comment: I added an update which illustrates the use of the list `words`. Basically you were creating a new string for every `+` that you called on your out_string. Storing the components in a `list` (words) is a common python idiom and used to generate longer strings more efficiently.

Comment: It only gives me the error:
words =[]
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Looks like the copy/paste didn't work for `words`. It needs to be indented correctly below the `for` loop declaration.